# Получение массива GameObject'ов, который касаются другого объекта

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я делаю 2D игру про алхимию: игрок должен соединять несколько элементов, чтобы получить другой.

Когда игрок соединяет элементы, я использую функцию OтCollisionStay, чтобы узнать, с каким элементом контактирует данный.

Но в некоторых случаях в соединении участвуют больше 2 элементов, в то время как OnCollisionStay возвращает только 1 объект, с которым контактирует данный. Как можно получить массив всех объектов, с которыми контактирует данный?

Мой скрипт, работающий для 2 объектов, выглядит так:

```
public class Element : MonoBehaviour
{
    /*...*/
    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (wasReleased)
        {
            Element otherElement = GetElement(collision);
            tryToConnect(otherElement);

            wasReleased = false;
        }
    }
}
```

- Мне нужна переменная wasReleased для того, чтобы элементы не соединялись, когда игрок просто перетаскивает один элемент над другим, не отпуская кнопку мыши.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка править

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам помогут методы `Physics.OverlapSphere`, `Physics.OverlapBox`, `Physics.OverlapCapsule`, в 2D скорее всего будет удобнее использовать `Physics2D.OverlapCollider` или `Collider2D.OverlapCollider`, хотя методы для сфер, боксов и прочего тоже присутствуют. Так же есть их аналоги с постфиксом `NonAlloc`, которые не аллоцируют новые массивы. Эти методы возвращают int, который показывает, сколько элементов было изменено в заранее созданном массиве.

Пример использования `OverlapSphereNonAlloc`

Допустим есть SphereCollider, который вы ставите в инспекторе

```
public SphereCollider collider;
private Collider[] results = new [10]; // создаем массив, в который будут класться коллайдеры

void CheckColliders()
{
    int resultsAmount = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(collider.transform.position + collider.center, collider.radius, results);
    // проходимся только по обновленным
    for (int i = 0; i < resultsAmount; i++)
    {
        var colliderInSphere = results[i];
        // делаем что-то дальше
    }
}
```

Все методы описаны в документации Unity.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html

Найдите в списке нужный вам.

UPD: Увидел, что у вас 2D.
Пример `Collider2D.OverlapCollider`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapCollider.html

```
public Collider2D col;
private Collider2D[] results = new Collider2D[10];

void CheckCollider()
{
    ContactFilter2D filter = new ContactFilter2D();
    int resultAmount = col.OverlapCollider(filter.NoFilter(), results);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < resultAmount; i++)
    {
        var colliderInCol = results[i];
    }
}
```

В вашем случае можно вызывать в `OnMouseUp()`

Comment: Спасибо. А зачем нужен цикл в конце, если предыдущей строкой мы уже записываем все объекты в массив results?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Как я написал в месте про методы `NonAlloc`, в массиве будут обновлены только первые `resultAmount` элементов. Остальные могут быть или старые (оставшиеся после другого вызова метода), или вообще `null`, поэтому нужно пройтись только по новым. Если нужна коллекция только с новыми элементами каждый раз, то вы можете заменить создание массива results при инициализации на создание листа, чистить этот лист при вызове, и передавать лист в OverlapCollider, но тогда лист будет изменяться каждый раз, что приведет к созданию мусора в памяти и лагам при сборе этого мусора

Comment: ОК, спасибо за помощь!